# How to sort data by the numbers in third column?

Tags: linux, shell, unix, text

If I have a file consisting of data that looks as follows, how would I sort the data based on the numbers in the third column?

The spaces between the first two columns are *not* tab delimited, but some number of spaces. The space between the second and third column varies based on the size of the number.

Also note that there are spaces within some data of the second column (like `lp25( plasmid` between `(` and `p`) while others do not have any spaces (like `chromosome`).

```
HELIX       lp25(plasmid           24437 bp    RNA     linear       29-AUG-2011
HELIX       cp9(plasmid             9586 bp    DNA     helix       29-AUG-2011
HELIX       lp28-1(plasmid         25455 bp    DNA     linear       29-AUG-2011
HELIX       chromosome            911724 bp    DNA     plasmid       29-AUG-2011
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go:

```
sort -n -k 3 test.txt
```

From [man sort](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/sort.1.html):

> ```
> -n, --numeric-sort          compare according to string numerical value
> -k, --key=KEYDEF          sort via a key; KEYDEF gives location and type
> ```
>
> KEYDEF is F[.C][OPTS][,F[.C][OPTS]] for start and stop position, where F is a
>   field number and C a character position in the field; both are origin 1, and
>   the stop position defaults to the line's end.  If neither -t nor -b is in
>   effect, characters in a field are counted from the beginning of the preceding
>   whitespace.  OPTS is one or more single-letter ordering options [bdfgiMhnRrV],
>   which override global ordering options for that key.  If no key is given, use
>   the entire line as the key.

and also interesting:

> -t, --field-separator=SEP  use SEP instead of non-blank to blank transition

which tells us that the `F` fields are separated by whitespace.